# standing WITH / IN / AT a 45-degree angle

Tags: prepositions

Which one below would be correct when explaining the way something stands ?

> 1) It was standing with a 45-degree angle.
>
> 2) It was standing a 45-degree angled.
>
> 3) It was standing in a 45-degree angled way.
>
> 4) It was standing in a manner angled to 45 degree.
>
> 5) It was standing in a manner with a 45-degree angle.

Answer (score 5):

None of those. What makes you think any of them are correct? (Edit: just wondering where this list came from; not intending to be rude!) Here is how you would say this:

> It was standing *at* a 45-degree angle.

2nd edit: for reference, see definition 1 here and the example sentence: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/angle

> *The boat is now leaning at a 30 degree angle.*

Comment: This answer might be a little bit snarky, but I must agree that it's strange to see 5 different examples and have none of them be correct!

Comment: I actually didn't mean to be snarky, so I apologize to @language learner if my response came off that way. I am honestly just wondering how OP came across this list.

Comment: I would want to know "at a 45-degree angle to _what_? The horizontal? The vertical? Some surface?